# Example of SORT_LOCALE_STRING making a difference in array_unique

Tags: php, arrays, locale

Is there any example of using SORT_LOCALE_STRING where it would give a different result to the default SORT_STRING when using array_unique?

Here is some code that shows how you can get different results between SORT_STRING, SORT_REGULAR, SORT_NUMERIC.

```
<?php
$list = array(
  '0',
  null,
  0,
  10,
  '10.0',
  '1e1',
  false,
  ''
);
var_dump(array_unique($list));
var_dump(array_unique($list, SORT_NUMERIC));
var_dump(array_unique($list, SORT_REGULAR));
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [1]=>
  NULL
  [3]=>
  int(10)
  [4]=>
  string(4) "10.0"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "1e1"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [3]=>
  int(10)
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [1]=>
  NULL
  [3]=>
  int(10)
  [7]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Please help me find an example that shows a use for SORT_LOCALE_STRING.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess in german, `ß` and `ss` are considered lexicographically equal I think. Basically, they should be considered the same character and sort as such. If you don't use a locale sensitive string comparison(sorting is string comparison), then, I think it's pretty obvious those two strings wont compare as being equal.

```
$array = array('ß', 't', 'ss');
//binary safe transport of the above chars as present in my text editor
$array = unserialize(base64_decode('YTozOntpOjA7czoxOiLfIjtpOjE7czoxOiJ0IjtpOjI7czoyOiJzcyI7fQ=='));
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'deu_deu');
echo setlocale(LC_ALL, '0'), "\n";
var_dump(strcoll('ß', 'ss'));
var_dump(array_unique($array, SORT_LOCALE_STRING));
```

yields, on my machine(win7, php5.4rc2)

```
German_Germany.1252
int(0)
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "ß"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "t"
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the reply. I also read that in theory what you said is true. I ran the code you gave me and I have the de_DE locale but it didn't filter any of the elements out. So I don't see how it makes any difference which is the question asked.

Comment: weird. it works on my machine.`setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'deu_deu');
echo setlocale(LC_COLLATE,'0');` yields `German_Germany.1252`

Comment: That looks like a Windows locale code. I'm on a Mac. Could you add your output to your answer.

Comment: Well I can't get it to work, but I trust you chris, you seem like a stand up guy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sort locale is basically sorting by currently set locale for ex:

```
$array = array('C', 'A', 'Ą');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'lt_LT');
sort($array, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);

var_dump($array)
//will output $array = array('Ą', 'A', 'C'), 
//without flag
//$array = array('A', 'C', 'Ą');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the question is how does this sorting (which is only done internally in array_unique) make a different when using array_unique. As you see by my example, depending on the flag you use, it will have an impact on what is filtered out as a duplicate.

Comment: Not a great example. According to [LST 1285:1993](http://www.likit.lt/all/rast_zen.htm), A and Ą should be treated equally when sorting. Not sure however, whether they should take any specific order if they are the last letters of the words, just as in your case.